# Git Remove commits from mistakenly added to branch from another branch

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have the following commit structure:

```
master  A                          A
        |\                         |\
user1   | B D E  ==> user2 pulls   | B D E
         \           from user 1    \
user2     C G H                      B C D E G H
```

Then I merge `user1` to `master`.

So master adds a merge commit E' and looks like:

```
A B D E E'
```

Then I go to review `user2's` code in GitHub and it shows all the code from `User1`.

Is there a way with git (or GitHub) to review only C, G, and H? Yes, I could review each commit individually, but this is a simplified example of what really happened.

I read the manual from git-rebase, and believe the answer is there, but I could not figure it out. I honestly tried to RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

IF B, D and E are the exact same in user2's branch, then Github would automatically show only the commits that are not already there on master.

You could also rebase user2's branch with master and achieve the same result.